# How do I check the Boolean value on eval() or if an arithmetic operation is false?

Tags: javascript

I am doing this for a calculator project, I want to check if the operation is valid or not, somehow I cannot check for the Boolean value of `eval` if it is `false`? on the console:

```
Boolean(eval('2+2(9.1-)9'));
Boolean(2+2(9.1-)9); // Both operations return unexpected token
```

unlike `Boolean(2+2)` <-- returns `true`. Help?

Comment: Why are you using eval in this situation? -- Also `2+2(9.1-)9` is invalid

Comment: What are you trying to do? `2+2(9.1-)9` doesn't make mathematical sense.

Comment: And what exactly does `2+2(9.1-)9` mean?

Comment: I am using other methods like map, on some operations where there are nested brackets like (2+(2(2))) I have to insert * on proper places before ( so it will become (2+(2*(2))) so i convert them to string  and use eval @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the only thing you want to know is "Is that a valid expression". One very simple way to check this is using `eval()` as you did here, and to enclose it in a `try`, and see if any error occurs. For example, you could write this :

```
try {
    eval('2+2(9.1-)9');
    valid = true;
} catch (e) {
    valid = false;
}
```

Then, the variable `valid` contains `true` if the expression is valid, and `false` if it is not.

Warning with `eval()` though : Every valid code will pass this test, not only mathematical expressions : Plus, that code will be executed. Be careful what strings you give it.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to evaluate the code in order to see if it's valid - just `try` creating a `Function`:

```js
function checkIt() {
  var fn

  try {
    var fn = new Function(document.getElementById("code").value)
    alert("Great, that's a valid piece of code!")
  } catch (e) {
    alert("That's not a valid piece of code.")
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="code">
<button onclick="checkIt()">Check it</button>
```

For example, try "123", "valid", and "''not[valid!!!".

Though if you *are* going to be evaluating it right away, if it's valid, you should probably just check if the error is a syntax error, or otherwise.

```js
function doIt() {
  var fn

  try {
    var result = eval(document.getElementById("code").value)
    alert("The result is: " + result)
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
      alert("That's not a valid piece of code.")
    } else {
      alert(e.message)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="code">
<button onclick="doIt()">Check it</button>
```

For example, try the same things you tried before and see how this behaves.